# Cannot create an image for Golang app using Docker

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I try to create an image for my Golang application, but Docker just writes:

```
Step 7/9 : RUN go install ./accounting/server
 ---> Running in f998ba6a5efb
can't load package: package grpcProjects/multiService/accounting/server: cannot find package "grpcProjects/multiService/accounting/server" in any of:
        /usr/local/go/src/grpcProjects/multiService/accounting/server (from $GOROOT)
        /go/src/grpcProjects/multiService/accounting/server (from $GOPATH)
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.10.4

ADD . /go/src/grpcProjects/multiService

WORKDIR /go/src/grpcProjects/multiService

RUN go get github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
RUN go get golang.org/x/net/context
RUN go get google.golang.org/grpc
RUN go install ./accounting/server

ENTRYPOINT [ "/go/bin/server" ]

EXPOSE 8080
```

Project structure:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this command `go install ./accounting/server` work for you when you run it locally?

Comment: @Nik yes, it does.

Comment: Probably you want to replace ADD with COPY command in Dockerfile & also doublc check if there is any .dockerignore file preventing from copying server package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution. Everything went wrong because I used this command from the root directory of the project:

```sh
$ docker build -t accounting_server ./accounting
```

And `multiService/accounting` was my building directory, so file hierarchy in the image looked like that:

```
/go/src/grpcProjects/multiService
/go/src/grpcProjects/multiService/server
/go/src/grpcProjects/multiService/server/service
/go/src/grpcProjects/multiService/server/service/accounting.go
/go/src/grpcProjects/multiService/server/main.go
/go/src/grpcProjects/multiService/proto
/go/src/grpcProjects/multiService/proto/accounting.proto
/go/src/grpcProjects/multiService/proto/accounting.pb.go
/go/src/grpcProjects/multiService/Dockerfile
```

**Docker** just copied the contents of local `/multiService/accounting` to `/multiService` directory of the image. So I had to change **Dockerfile** a bit:

```
FROM golang:1.10.4

ADD . /go/src/grpcProjects/multiService

RUN go get github.com/golang/protobuf/proto
RUN go get golang.org/x/net/context
RUN go get google.golang.org/grpc
RUN go install grpcProjects/multiService/accounting/server

ENTRYPOINT [ "/go/bin/server" ]

EXPOSE 8080
```

And I built my container with the next command:

```sh
$ docker build -t accounting_server -f ./accounting/Dockerfile .
```

Still from the root directory so everything was copied to the image properly.

Thanks to everyone who replied!